# Where did cakephp 1.3 save the uploaded files?

Tags: php, file, cakephp, upload

I'm working on APP and I don't know where cakephp save the files.

When I make directory un /app/webroot with the same name an error appears.

Comment: You'll want to supply more information and clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP never saved files by default anywhere. It is up to the user of the framework (you) to implement that.